# Hibernate: Fetching columns with their aliases

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Consider this trivial query:

`SELECT 1 as first, 2 as second`

When using Hibernate we can then do something like:

`em.createNativeQuery(query).fetchResultList()`

However, there seem to be no way of getting the aliases (or column names). This would be very helpful for creating `List<Map<String, Object>>` where each map would be a row with their aliases, for instance in this case: `[{first: 1, second: 2}]`.

Is there a way to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ResultTransformer interface . Implement custom mapper for mapping values with aliases.
here is example https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-use-the-hibernate-resulttransformer-to-customize-result-set-mappings/

with ResultTransformer you can easy customize result set type , especially if you need aliases

Comment: The article actually really helped - I previously tried to use  `ResultTransformer` without effect. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Maybe you can help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585825/correct-cast-in-resulttransformer

Comment: Use object wrapers not primitives. What  db do you use?oracle,mysql,postgressql... there might be problem with some types

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a bit different approach which may meet your needs.

In JPA 2.1 there is a feature called "result set mapping".

Basically you have to define a POJO class which would hold the result values (all the values must be passed using the constructor):

```
public class ResultClass{

    private String fieldOne;
    private String fieldTwo;

    public ResultClass(String fieldOne, String fieldTwo){
        this.fieldOne = fieldOne;
        this.fieldTwo = fieldTwo;
    }
}
```

Then you have to declare the mapping on one of your entities (does not matter on which, it just has to be a declated @Entity):

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="ResultMapping", classes = {
    @ConstructorResult(targetClass = ResultClass.class, 
    columns = {@ColumnResult(name="columnOne"), @ColumnResult(name="columnTwo")})
})
```

The `columnOne` and `columnTwo` are aliases as declared in the select clause of the native query.

And finally use in the query creation:

```
List<ResultClass> results = em.createNativeQuery(query, "ResultMapping").getResultList();
```

In my opinion this is more elegant and "a level above" solution as you are not working with a generic Map key/values pairs but with a concrete POJO class.

Comment: What I don't like is that I have to name the columns on more places: 1. In the class, in the mapping and in the query. Honestly I would like to avoid the mapping so that it would be mapped by the aliases directly on the class. Also I don't like the fact, that the `@SqlResultSetMapping` has to be annotated on completely different class. What seems to me interesting is `AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer`, but it is available only to criteria queries.