# Correct cast in ResultTransformer

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am using Hibernate result transformer for fetching list of results from the database as follows:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT 1 as myTrueBoolean, 2 as myInt")
query.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).setResultTransformer‌​(Transformers.aliasT‌​oBean(myDataClass));
query.fetchResultList()
```

Than I could define a data class as follows:

```
class MyDataClass {
    boolean myTrueBoolean;
    int myInt;
}
```

The problem is that the transformer will not cast correctly the data as it will assign BigInteger as boolean (`IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [MyDataClass.myTrueBoolean (expected type = boolean)]; target = MyDataClass, property value = [0]]`) and the same with assigning BigInteger as int. This wouldn't be a problem with general Hibernate entities.

EDIT:

I am not looking for explanation why it does not work. I am looking for a way to making it work :-) I need this for my native queries. Is there maybe a way of implementing own transformer which would achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For native SQL queries you get whatever the database returns. That is kind of the point with native SQL queries. For MySQL it returns `BigInteger` ,but for `MsSQL` it can return `Integer`.

Change your class to

```
class MyDataClass {
    Number myTrueBoolean;
    Number myInt;
}
```

Another option is to use JPA queries. They will return types of values from your entities.

Comment: This would be obvious way of making it work. But it is not what I want, I want to use the correct type of each field.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible with native queries.